# dot sourcing with relative paths in powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am trying to figure out how to use relative paths for Powershell scripts. I have dot sourced with absolute paths, but the scripts that I am writing may end up in a different base directory so I need to make sure the path is relative so it can be picked up.  How can I do that?

So far I have tried:

```
. .\scripts\variables.ps1
```

That always throws this exception:

```
The term '.\scripts\variables.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program...
```

That lets me know it can't find my script?  So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your error message says `\scripts\variables.ps1`, not `.\scripts\variables.ps1`. Are you sure you tried `. .\scripts\variables.ps1` and not `. \scripts\variables.ps1`?

Comment: positive.  I apologize as I typed out the error message and forgot the period.

Comment: In that case `.\scripts` is relative to what `get-location` tells you (i.e., the current location).

Answer (score 13):

You can use : `. $PSScriptRoot\scripts\variables.ps1` 
Here `$PSScriptRoot` is the path of directory of the running script.

Answer (score 6):

This is not what the OP asked for but may be useful for others who are searching:

If you need to traverse up, you can use . `$PSScriptRoot\..\scripts\variables.ps1`

This works for structures such as:

- root

  - scripts/shared directory
  - directory your script is executing in

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful, I was looking how to traverse up

Answer (score 1):

If you know that your script directory structure is going to remain the same, you could use `$PWD`; eg:

```
. "$PWD\scripts\variables.ps1"
```

The above assumes that your script (the calling script) is in the same directory that contains the `scripts` directory.
Also, the assumption made here is that you're checking out/downloading all your scripts in the same structure, but as you put it, they may end up being in a different base directory.